# Calculus Optimization

Tags: calculus

There are $50$ apple trees in an orchard. Each tree produces $800$ apples. For each additional tree planter in the orchard, the output per tree drops by $10$ apples.

I'm not sure if what my function in terms of the number of trees that models the total production of apples would be. I'm pretty sure it's $a(x)=(50+x)(800-10x)$.

Also, what is the implied domain and range of the function used?

Comment: your function seems to be right. For domain you need $0 \leq x \leq 80$. The upper cap of $80$ is because after $80$ you will not be producing any more apples. Now you can apply calculus techniques to optimize. Don't forget to check the end-points for greatest/least values.

Comment: Presumably your $x$ represents the number of additional trees planted beyond $50$.  I would say your expression looks fine.  I think $x$ could be negative (you could decrease the number of trees, thus increasing the yield per tree).  I would say that the domain of values for $x$ is $-50\le x\le 80$.  Also in the context of the actual situation, $x$ should be an integer.

Comment: I'm confused here: if the function is $(50+x)(800-10x)$, then if I plant 5 trees my yield is
$(55)(750) = 41250$, but if do this manually I have a yeild of:
800x50 = existing yield - 40000 +790+780+770+760+750 = 43850 which is not the same. Furthermore, as an optimization problem it seems we need to know the price of a tree. If the trees are free then we should just keep adding trees until we get no more apples (79 trees). Where am I going wrong here? Chris.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modelling the number of apples an orchard yields with diminishing returns per tree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3790938/modelling-the-number-of-apples-an-orchard-yields-with-diminishing-returns-per-tr)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some missing information here.

How many trees can each tree planter plant per unit time?

Or are we assuming that each tree planter only plants 1 tree?

It wasn't completely clear what you are trying to optimize. Are you trying to optimize (maximize) the total number of apples produced in a single season?

If each planter only plants a single tree, then the production function for a season would be
\begin{equation*}
f(x) = (50 + x)(800 - 10x)
\end{equation*}
as you wrote above. This function is a polynomial, and so its domain is potentially all of $\mathbb{R}$. However, it is only physically meaningful to consider values of $x$ which are non-negative and which don't yield a negative production. Thus the (feasible) domain is $[0,80]$. It is also quadratic (you can expand out the terms), and the coefficient on $x^{2}$ is negative, and thus it will have a unique maximum value, which I'm just going to label $M$ for the time being. In this case, the range of the function $f(x)$ is $(-\infty, M]$.

Comment: So my maximum value would be 15, what would my domain be?

Comment: @Mark the range will be $[0,M]$ because of the restriction of feasible domain.